# How to change walllpaper in c using winapi?

Tags: c

I tried this but it does not work

```
LPWSTR test = L"C:\\Users\\Default\\wallpaper.png";
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, test, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx) says that the file must be a bitmap (or, possibly, a JPG).

Comment: so, how to convert a .png to .bmp using winapi? =\

Comment: @Ninja - that's a completely different question, start another one.